How to get WordPress Dataviews component responsive?
I'm using dataviews WordPress component on my plugin.
Is there a way to do this component responsive? I'd like to hide some columns when I resize the screen to mobile devices.
On official documents I don't see anything about that.
I could do this with css media query classes but I don't know how to assing css for each column.
DOCS:
